# Annotating line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having troubles annotating my line chart.

This is what I have tried:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame([int(one.values), int(two.values),int(three.values),int(four.values),int(five.values),int(six.values),int(seven.values),int(eight.values),int(nine.values)],columns=['col'])
ax = frame.unstack().plot(marker='o')
a = frame['col'].tolist()
for i in a: 
    ax.text(str(i),xy=i)
```

This gives me the following error message:

> TypeError: text() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 's'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide first the x-coordinate, then the y-coordinate and then the string. Suppose the x-position is `x_pos` and y-position is `y_pos`, then you can use

```
for i in a: 
    ax.text(x_pos, y_pos, str(i))
```

Comment: Works, struggling to get the co-ordinates to match the markers

Comment: @Emm Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)